# How to handle string input in Classes..?

Tags: c++

what happend to the getline() function when i take string input of the second object..why it doesn't work properly..Plz Explain about that which is the right function to get string input and how i can solved out this problem?

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>
using namespace  std;
class Result 
{
    private:
    string Name;
    int  i, subject_marks[3] , roll_num , sum;
    float average;
    public:
    void Input()
    {
      cout<<"Enter the Student Name:";
      getline(cin,Name);
      cout<<"Enter the Roll Number:";
      cin>>roll_num;
      cout<<"Enter the Marks of the 3 Subject"<<endl;
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      cin>>subject_marks[i];    
    }
    void show()
    {
      cout<<"Name of the Student:"<<Name<<endl; 
      cout<<"Roll Number of the Student:"<<roll_num<<endl;
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      cout<<"Subject Marks of the Student:"<<subject_marks[i]<<endl;
    }   
    int Sum()
    {
        sum=0;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
       sum+=subject_marks[i];
       return sum;
    }
    float Average()
    {
        return average=sum/3.0;
    }
    
};

int main(void)

{
    Result Student1,Student2;
    Student1.Input();
    cout<<endl<<"Detail of the Student"<<endl;
    Student1.show();
    cout<<"Sum Of the Subjects:"<<Student1.Sum()<<endl;
    cout<<"Average of the Subjects:"<<Student1.Average()<<endl<<endl;
    Student2.Input();
    cout<<endl<<"Detail of the Student"<<endl;
    Student2.show();
    cout<<"Sum Of the Subjects:"<<Student2.Sum()<<endl;
    cout<<"Average of the Subjects:"<<Student2.Average()<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" - please describe what you expect and what actually happened.

Comment: With your formatting I'd advise you to not use the same intendation for visibility and members (usually I use the same intendation for the opening `{` of the class and visibilities); this makes it much easier to find the visibility of a member.

Comment: i want to know that why it doesn't take input of the second object...?